# Why can't Piper sidestep this dilemma?

Tags: plot-explanation, orange-is-the-new-black

In Orange is the New Black, Piper testifies in court regarding a certain person in her life. The question is whether or not to tell the truth, and Piper considers it a real dilemma because

> she has reason to believe she'll be murdered unless she lies under oath.

The problem would likely be fixed if she were to

> request some sort of protection,

but she doesn't. Why not?

Comment: Haven't seen the show but Witness Protection has different levels depending on whether it's a state or federal crime. In most cases they only protect you **while** you are a witness. Once the trial is over...you're on your own. Being **disappeared** into Federal Witness Protection is quite rare and not as intense as it often appears on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC, Piper lies because **she's in love with Vause**, and if she tells the truth then Vause will likely be hunted down and killed by Kubra (Vause's old boss whom Piper is testifying against.  If she goes into the Witness Protection Program, she can never see Vause again, and she's not willing to do that.